# Java.util.ArrayList hashCode is returning not so random values on a Storm topology

Tags: java, clojure, apache-storm

I am facing a strange problem with the hashCode returned for an ArrayList. Below is the modified tuple.clj (from Apache Storm source). The list passed to list-hash-code is a list of Strings. The hashcode returned are such that (returned-has-code % 6) is always 4. I.e. "(mod (.hashCode alist) 6)" is always 4. I am really confused what may be going wrong. Because of this issues the tuple distribution across next bolt task is not being proper. I am clueless about what may be going wrong here. The same issue I don't see I run the things from clojure REPL.

How can I know which hashCode function is being used? Is there anyway to check the method details and of a Java class method from Clojure ?

```
(ns backtype.storm.tuple
  (:use [backtype.storm bootstrap])
  )

(bootstrap)
(defn- print-comma-list [^List els ]
  (let [ret (StringBuilder. ) ]
    (do 
      (loop [iter (.iterator els) ]
        (when (.hasNext iter)
            (.append (.append ret (.next iter)) ",")
            (recur iter))))
      (.toString ret)))

(defn list-hash-code [^List alist comp-id group-id ]
  (do
    (if ( and (= comp-id "test1-bolt") ( = group-id "field1,"))
        (log-message "Hashcode returned: " (.hashCode alist) " mod val " (mod (.hashCode alist) 6) " " (print-comma-list alist)))
    (.hashCode alist)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `hashcode` for a Java `ArrayList` is not at all "random".

It is actually using an algorithm *specified* in the Java `List` API that combines the element hashcodes in a predictable way; see [this javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--).  If the elements of the list have predictable order and predictable hashcodes, then the list hashcode is predictable.

The algorithm is this (in Java):

```
 int hashCode = 1;
 for (E e : list)
     hashCode = 31 * hashCode + (e == null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
```

---

> Is there anyway to check the method details and of a Java class method from Clojure ?

The Java source code and javadocs are freely available.

However checking "method details" *from Clojure* is not supported ... assuming that the "method details" you are interested in is the algorithm.  (Indeed, it is not supported for Java programs either!)  I suppose, you could programatically lookup the bytecodes and call some application to disassemble or decompile them.  But there isn't much point ... given that the real source code of `java.util.*` is included in every Oracle JDK installer.

Comment: Thanks Stephen C. But the problem I am facing is, when the "list-hash-code" is invoked from a Storm topoloy, the returned values are such that "(mod the-returned-hash 6)" is always 4. Hence, always task 4 in the next step is processing the data.  Is there any way to print the bytecode of a method and also the package location from where the class is loaded?

Comment: What do think you are going to achieve by printing the bytecodes loaded, and where they are loaded from???  As far as I can tell, the `hashcode` method is behaving how it is specified to behave!

Comment: Then I can see if they are tampered with. Basically, 
I want to see the hashCode source. With Java and Eclipse, it is easy. I just put a break in the hashCode invocation line or in that method and step into and I see the source code for hashCode. But my difficulty is, here it is Clojure calling java and things are not that easy and cannot do much from Eclipse.

Comment: If you even *suspect* that your Java installation has been tampered with, just reinstall it.  But this sounds like a waste of time.  As I said, hashcode is behaving as it is supposed to behave.  Lists containing the same elements in the same order **will** have the same hashcode.  It is how the class is **designed to work**.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion.
 
The list passed to list-hash-code are generally having random (UUID strings).

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke .getClass .getCanonicalName, you'll get the full name of the class that implements List that is being used. Hashcode for the default AbstractList in Oracle JDK is included in Stephen C.'s answer. If that's the source being used, there would be no particular reason for such anomaly if the strings are different, though it depends on your data.

Note that hashCode() is not guaranteed to be uniformly distributed at all. It is correct to have hashCode() return 1 for all instances of the class as long as the equals() function distinguishes different instances of the class. That's because hashCode represents 'weak equality', objects that are equal must have the same hashCode (to be correctly found by HashMap for example), but the reverse is not true. This means that you can modify hashCode to something else, for example List,hashCode times a prime, as long as your function from old hashcode to new hashcode maps identical input to identical output (no random element).